# How to remove '\x00' from list

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I would like to know, how can I delete or rather replace '\x00' in my list with ''.
I have list like this

`[['a', '7', '9', 'd', '4', 'e'], ['\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', 'b', 'f']]`

and I want to have `[['a', '7', '9', 'd', '4', 'e'], ['', '', '', '', 'b', 'f']]`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you tried anything with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could iterate over it and only copy strings if they are not `\x00` (`l` is the list)

```py
result = []
for sub_l in l:
    new_sub_l = []
    for s in sub_l:
        if s != '\x00':
           new_sub_l.append(s)
    result.append(new_sub_l)
```

or use list comprehension:

```py
result = [[s for s in sub_l if s != '\x00'] for sub_l in l]
```

or replace instead of delete:

```py
result = [[s.replace('\x00', '') for s in sub_l] for sub_l in l]
```